# binary files in team foundation server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, repository, foxpro

We recently switched to team foundation server 2010 for our source code management, everything works just fine, except for some legacy code written in FoxPRO 7 and 9, source code files are some sort of tables. For Forms, there are two kind of files, one ending in .scx and another in .sct, both can be explored using the fox studio but there is no way to open them in a text editor.

does anyone have any experience getting the fox code to work/merge... on TFS ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? A list of all operations you need to do with TFS that don't work with fox code would help a lot (I never worked with fox forms, but perhaps I can still help if I know what doesn't work).

Comment: @SvenS The problem that he is going to run into is that FoxPro uses FoxPro tables, instead of text files to store source code.  For example, both the form design, and the code-behind for forms is in tables.  To the best of my knowledge, those files are hostile to any source control tool.  He can configure TFS to treat them as binary files and not source (so no text diffing/merging/multiple checkout/etc) allowed.  I put the details in my answer below).

Comment: There are various solutions to allow VFP to collaborate with source control tools. Among them is a program that comes with VFP called scctext.prg; it converts those binaries into text files.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of all of the ins and outs for source control and FoxPro, but if some of the source is binary, you can configure file extensions to disallow merges.

Right-click on the collection (root node) in the TeamExplorer window.  Go to Team Project Collection Settings | File Types.

You should be able to add the extensions (like .sct), and specify that merging and multiple checkout is not allowed for those files.

The downside will be that only 1 person at a time can check those files out, but since the forms are FoxPro tables, I would imagine that's the same problem that you would have with any source control tool.

Comment: That's exactly what it is, but then with 3 developers, each working on different tasks and having different versions of code ( some could have check out 3 weeks ago, another one this morning...) putting together all the changes is not only daunting but impossible without manual interventions

Comment: Another downside implied by the one you listed: You will have MAJOR problems if you use the TFS Build system with shelvesets. But I suppose you won't use TFS Build with FoxPro, will you? ;)

Answer (score 1):

For merging you can set up a merge tool that is capable of merging those files. This must be done on every developer station (Tools->Source Control->VS Team Foundation Server->Configure User Tools).

It may be that VS uses a server-side merge tool to do auto-merges, I don't know if or where you can change that.

Comment: what kind of merge tool ? on client side ?

Comment: Oh, I was assuming there was a tool that could merge those files, but this doesn't seem to be the case, is it? If there was one, you could tell Visual Studio to open it when the user manually resolves a conflict. But if there is no way to merge the files at all, then I don't see a way how TFS can do it, and I don't see any way around it but the one JMarsch proposed: auto-lock on those files on checkout.

Comment: Yeah, the only solution is
convert binary to text
store text using tfs
convert text to binary
Microsoft is a joke

that was my first poem, enjoy !!! :)

Comment: Well, personally I think FoxPro is to blame for using binary format to store data that is supposed to be merge-able ;) For once, Microsoft is not to blame ^^

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with VFP since it was FoxBase back in late 80's.  Visual Foxpro used .dbf files (renamed extensions) for purposes of building forms (.scx/.sct) and visual class libraries (.vcx/.vct) and reports (.frx/.frt).

I've written some code to run through a given project and dump out a text version of all the code as if it was all text-based.  All the controls are dumped in alpha order, embedded procedures, etc too.  List all property settings in same place too.

Its not PERFECT, but I've used over the years in comparing source code versions when dealing with other developers who liked to change things and not notify me (or others) of such changes and finding later by other horrendous means.

If this is something you might be interested in, I can strip-down the code (some) and send it to you via an email, but would need an email address.  The code is written in VFP as a .prg file, so nothing compiled that you would need to worry about any viruses or anything.

At least this way, you COULD get a text version associated with the binary pair's of files used within VFP.